# $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\cos(2x)}{\cos x+\sin x}dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometry, riemann-integration

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\cos(2x)}{\cos x+\sin x}dx}$$

I don't know how to evaluate this integral. This is a path that I've tried:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\cos(2x)}{\cos x+\sin x}dx} =$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{\cos^2x - \sin^2x}{\cos x+\sin x}dx} =$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{1-2\sin^2x}{\cos x+\sin x}dx}$$

My idea was: let $t = \sin x$. Then $dt = \cos x dx$. But I only have $\frac{1}{\cos x}$. Any hints as to how to proceed from there?

This integral is giving me a hard time.

Comment: $(a^2 - b^2) = (a - b)(a + b)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: Notice, that:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\cos^2x - \sin^2x}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}}dx=
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{(\cos{x} - \sin{x})(\cos{x}+\sin{x})}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}}dx=
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\cos{x}-\sin{x}\right)dx$$

Comment: Man I feel so damn silly... I had thought about this for a second but for some reason I decided to go the other path. Thank you!

Comment: @SamueleB. no problem! Have a great New Year!

Comment: Same to you man!